# Why circle is not properly centered on a grid?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I cannot understand why my circle is not centered properly in a grid but looks rather shifted. Not sure what can affect this. I have the following sizes of container that contains bunch of cells of size cell_side_len* cell_side_len. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ph2avtLo/2/)

```
  var radius = 40;
        var cell_side_len = 200;
        var container_width = 400;
        var container_height = 300;

        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        container.style.width = (grid_width*2)+"px";
        container.style.height = (grid_height*2)+"px";

        for(var i = 0; i < grid_width*2/cell_side_len; i++){
         for(var j = 0; j < grid_height*2/cell_side_len; j++){
          var cell = document.createElement('div');
          cell.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
          cell.style.height = cell_side_len + 'px';
          cell.style.width = cell_side_len + 'px';
          cell.style.border = "1px solid black";
          cell.style.float = "left";
          cell.style.position = "relative";
          container.appendChild(cell);
        }
       }
        var circle = document.createElement('circle');
        circle.style.cssText = ' width: 40px; height: 40px; -webkit-border-radius: 25px; -moz-border-radius: 25px; border-radius: 25px; position: absolute; z-index: 9;';

        var style = window.getComputedStyle(circle);
        var left_val = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left").slice(0, -2));
        var top_val = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top").slice(0, -2)); 
        circle.style.left = 200 + "px";
        circle.style.top = 200 + "px";
        circle.style.background = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
            container.appendChild(circle);






    <div id="container"></div>
```

I get stuff like this while I expected it to be perfectly centered. 
How do I deal with it?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Can you add your html to replicate and debug

Comment: The formula for this without using canvas, which you really should be using for this instead, is `circle_left_edge = container_width/2-circle_width/2`.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO there is nothing more than <div id="container"></div>

Comment: @PHPglue what is this canvas? sorry I have no clue.. its my first time using JS.. lol

Comment: i see no circle on your fiddle

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I think I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason why your circle is positioned badly is because it isn't taking into account the positions of the grid itself (body margin), the circles radius (to position it centred), and the grids outer border (3px). To fix this problem set your body css to:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

And change your circle positioning lines to:

```
circle.style.left = 200 - 20 + 3 + "px";    
circle.style.top = 200 - 20 + 3 + "px";
```

The `20` is the circle radius, and the `3` is the grid outer border size. You can see an example in the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ph2avtLo/8/).

---

However, all this manipulation feels like a nightmare. You really should be using a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) to do graphics like this. It is more powerful, and will be faster. Better yet, use one of the many excellent [canvas libraries](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=canvas+library).

Comment: I see, so in my original code I also have a button and input field on top and they also affect this stupid circle position. How would I make circle position relative to parent div and not window?

Comment: yeah I figured it. I need to make parent's position relative.

Comment: Don't make the parents position relative. Make the circles position relative, and use `display: block`. You still need to minus the radius from the position though so it takes the circles centre, and not the top left.

Comment: thank you. I will look into canvas, but yeah.. I haven't done it before so dunno what to do with it ) Thanks for help